# Translate element up and affect flow

Tags: html, css

I want to translate an element upwards and cause the document flow to shift as well. In this example:

https://codepen.io/jauhar/pen/JjomyzO

```
<div class="x">
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
</div>

.x {
  background-color: purple;
}

.a {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
}

.b {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;

  position: relative;
  top: -50px;
}
```

I shifted an element upwards to overlap, however I would like the document to end at the element's new position. In other words, the purple part should not show in the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `margin` instead of `top`. The `top` property moves the element, independent of document flow and essentially keeps the elements original position in the document flow, rather than affecting it.

```css
.x {
  background-color: purple;
}

.a {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: green;
}

.b {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="x">
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```